# C, memory corruption(fast) error on free()

Tags: c, memory, malloc, free

So i have been working on a merge sort method that uses generic types as input and sorts them. I'm getting an error i don't understand. Because i use generic types and need to sort 20 kk records, i must use the malloc function to dinamically allocate the arrays i use to implement the merge sort, and therefore need to free them as soon as they are not needed anymore to avoid filling up all my memory. Here is the code (i will only put the relevant piece of code):

## Code

```
void merge(void ** A, int a, void ** B, int b, void ** C , CompFunction compare)
{

    int i,j,k;
    i=0;
    j=0;
    k=0;
    while(i < a && j < b){
        if((compare(A[i],B[j])<0)){
            C[k++] = A[i++];
        }
        else{
            C[k++] = B[j++];

        }

    }
    while(i < a){
        C[k++] = A[i++];
    }
    while(j < b){
        C[k++] = B[j++];
    }


}
  void merge_sort(void** A, int n, CompFunction compare)
{
int i;
    void ** A1;
    void ** A2;
    int n1,n2;
    if(n < 2)return;
    n1 = n/2;
    n2 = n - n1;
    A1 = malloc(sizeof(sizeof(void*))*n1);
    A2 = malloc(sizeof(sizeof(void*))*n2);
    printf("i:%d\n",i);
    for(i = 0 ; i < n2 ; i++){
        A1[i] = A[i];
    }
    for(i = 0 ; i < n2 ; i++){
        A2[i] = A[i+n1];
    }       
    merge_sort(A1, n1, compare);
    merge_sort(A2 ,n2, compare);
    merge(A1, n1, A2, n2, A, compare);
    free(A1);
    free(A2);
}
```

You'll see i call a compare function in the function parameters. That's simply a function that compares various types of data to determine which one is bigger or smaller.
I've tried to remove both the free() and the error no longer shows, however the code never ends running because it fills up all the memory and the swap area on the hdd.
The error I get is this:

## Error

```
*** Error in `./exeInt': malloc(): memory corruption       
(fast):0x00000000006dffa0 ***
```

If someone could help me i would deeply appreaciate it.

Comment: Smells like an off by one error.

Comment: Please show a [MCVE].

Comment: The for A[1] must run up to n1

Comment: You aren't checking the result of malloc.

Comment: @MichaelWalz Thank you for your consideration, monkeyStix solved it :)

Comment: What is "20 kk"? And why not use variable length arrays (VLA)? If you are after speed, `malloc` & friends are the last I'd use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
A1 = malloc(sizeof(sizeof(void*))*n1);
```

this is your problem, lets evaluate this first sizeof(void *), that is 8 byte(in a 64 bit system). then you do multiply it by n1 which is an int, which causes the result to evaluate to an int, therefore you get 4 bytes * n1 and not 8 bytes like i assume you want.

Comment: sizeof returns size_t

Comment: @monkeyStix your quote says "integer constant", not `int`.

Comment: Thank you, that was it. Actually i don't really know why I was doing all of that, i just needed a sizeof(void*)*n1. Thank you again :)

Comment: you are correct guys, it does evaluate to size_t, just checked.
although it does evaluate to int apparently if it fixed the problem

Comment: @monkeyStix: Please provide a reference where the C11 standard states `sizeof` returns an `int`. It returns a `size_t`! And where a pointer is required to have a size of 8 bytes (or the other values you assume). Also inspect the parentheses carefully.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is the problem, but at least one issue is:

```
for(i = 0 ; i < n2 ; i++){
   A1[i] = A[i];
}
for(i = 0 ; i < n2 ; i++){
    A2[i] = A[i+n1];
}
```

The first for loop should be `(...; i < n1;...)`. It might be you're overflowing the array.

Also, as others have mentioned, you're not checking the return value of `malloc`, though this is not the issue. Note that `malloc` will return `NULL` on failure.

Comment: Thank you for your consideration, but it appears the problem was elsewere :)